# mySQL CREATE TABLE UNIQUE INDEX

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm reading some examples of creating tables in MySQL but I'm not understanding the last statement on the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE 'company_test', 'employee'(
    ...
    UNIQUE INDEX 'department_id_UNIQUE' ('department_id' ASC) VISIBLE
)
```

what does this `UNIQUE INDEX 'department_id_UNIQUE ('department_id' ASC) VISIBLE` do? I went searching everywhere that could explain this but I could only find examples using `CREATE INDEX` outside CREATE TABLE, what does an index do and somebody can explain in detail that statement? If you could show me some documents talking about that I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. What does this statement do?**
UNIQUE INDEX 'department_id_UNIQUE ('department_id' ASC) VISIBLE

This statement creates unique index on department_id column of employee table in your example.
Index can be created during table creation as well as at later time after table is created.
MySQL Create table syntax: [create table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)
Index creation after table creation: [create index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html)

**2. What does index do?**
Index improves read performance at the cost of write performance.In you example alongwith index it creates unique constraint on columns which will prevent duplicate values for department_id field.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work) post explains how database indexing works in details.

Answer (score 1):

> UNIQUE INDEX 'department_id_UNIQUE ('department_id' ASC) VISIBLE

```
UNIQUE -- an index BTree is built and maintained; a uniqueness constraint is established.
INDEX -- optional (redundant) syntax
'...' -- optional arbitrary name for this index.  A default will be provided if left out.
(...) -- The column(s) in the index.  The combination is unique; the BTree is ordered by them.
ASC -- Ascending (as opposed to DESC: Descending)
VISIBLE -- below
```

`VISIBLE` is a new keyword.  Some products tack this on; some other products see it as a syntax error.  If that is a problem, simply remove the word.

The purpose of `VISIBLE` and `INVISIBLE` is thus.  `CREATEing` and `DROPping` an index is potentially a costly action.  If you want to remove the index (to save disk space), it can be advantageous to make it `INVISIBLE` to see if any query slows down drastically.  That might tell you that the index *is* needed.  Then you can quickly make it `VISIBLE` again.  Else you can `DROP` it.

`VISIBLE` is the default; leaving it off is OK.